# Checking if two elements match in a nested list (python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a list of the format:

```
my_list= [['ezis', 0], ['camera', 15], ['size', 0], ['esu', 16], ['take', 4],
 ['pictur', 26], ['tnaw', 46], ['thing', 49], ['ilno', 8],.....]
```

and I would like to see if the number at the end matches the reverse of the string (for example, in this list `['ezis', 0]` and `['size', 0]` would match with one another as they both have 0 as its end value and 'size' reversed is 'ezis'. I would then like to keep a count of the number of these matches.

So far I have:

```
matches = 0

for x,y in my_list:
    if (x[0]==y[0][::-1]) and x[1]==y[1]:
        matches+=1    #a match is found
```

But I am getting an error and am not sure how else to approach this

Could anyone help?

Comment: Should `size` and `ezis` count as 2 or 1?

Comment: What is the error you get? Why do you expect that code to work? `for x, y in my_list` sets `x = 'ezis'` and `y = 0` in the first iteration. Your code doesn't compare the strings in the sub-lists with each other. All it does is compare the first character of `x` with the "first element" of `y` (which isn't possible since `y` is an integer), and the second character of `x` with the second element of `y` (again, `y` is an integer so this isn't possible)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> sum(1 for k, v in dict(my_list).items() if v==dict(my_list).get(k[::-1]))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the counter class (from collection) to get all the counts in a dictionary.

If you want each "duplicate" to appear only once with the count of both string order:

```
my_list= [['ezis', 0], ['camera', 15], ['size', 0], ['esu', 16], ['take', 4],
          ['pictur', 26], ['tnaw', 46], ['thing', 49], ['ilno', 8]]

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter((max(s,s[::-1]),n) for s,n in my_list)

print(counts)
Counter({('size', 0): 2, ('camera', 15): 1, ('use', 16): 1, ('take', 4): 1, 
         ('rutcip', 26): 1, ('want', 46): 1, ('thing', 49): 1, 
         ('onli', 8): 1})
```

If you only want counts for matching pairs:

```
counts    = Counter(map(tuple,my_list))
revCounts = { (s,n):counts[s[::-1],n] for s,n in counts if counts[s[::-1],n]}

print(revCounts)
{('ezis', 0): 1, ('size', 0): 1}
```